# how to optimize nested loop query

Tags: sql-server, nested-loops, query-performance

I have a cte and i am using nested loop joins to fetch the data from 3 different tables. The performance is very slow and after sometime I get a timeout error. I checked the query plan and found that the issue is with the nested loop joins.

How do I optimize the below query? Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated.

```
with DCT as(
    select distinct
           p.PolicyReference as PolicyNumber,
           Year(p.PolicyEffectiveDate) as PolicyYear,
           reverse(substring(reverse(p.PolicyReference) , 1 , 2 )) as 
           PolicySequence,
           p.PolicyEffectiveDate as InceptionDate,
           p.PolicyExpirationDate as ExpirationDate,
           p.AggregateLimitAmt_Orginal as AggregateLimit,
           p.AttachmentPointAmt_Orginal as AttachmentPoint,                   
           ch.DangerSignalDescription as DangerDescription,
           ct.TransactiomAmountOriginal,
           ch.PrimaryAllegation,
           p.LOBCode as GLLOBCode, 
           p.BusinessUnit as GLLOBName,
           p.ProducingOfficeCode as Office, 
           Null as CatCode,
           p.PolicyBasisCode as PolicyTrigger,
           Getdate() As ProcessDate,
    From [vwPolicy] p 
        Inner  Join [vwClaimHeader] ch  ON p.PolicyReference = ch.PolicyReference 
        Inner  Join [vwClaimTransactions] ct ON ch.ClaimSuffix = ct.ClaimSuffix)
select * from DCT;
```

I have attached the query plan execution and as you can see nested loops take 82%. How do I overcome this. It's a pretty straight forward query.
[image]

Comment: A few pointers: 1. White space is your friend. 2. `;` is a terminator, not a "beginninator". ([Deprecated Features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017) - *"Deprecated Feature: Not **ending** Transact-SQL statements with a semicolon. - Solution: **End** Transact-SQL statements with a semicolon (`;`).*. 3. Don't post images of Execution Plans, use [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). On a different note, why are you using a CTE here when are you do is a `SELECT *` from it?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your inputs. Its a part of the stored proc where I have to union between 2 cte's. I was trying to investigate the performance issue , so just ran this particular cte outside the sp to check.

Comment: Since you are joining with views, also you need to post that views sql as well.
Also do you have proper indexes?

Comment: Those are views to linked servers? Can you do joining on the other server?

Comment: Good spot @Veijo .

Comment: @RezaRahmati-- i just found out the views are not indexed. So what would be the solution